# Using IPython / Jupyter Notebooks Under Version Control

Tags: version-control, ipython, jupyter-notebook

What is a good strategy for keeping [IPython](http://ipython.org) notebooks under version control?

The notebook format is quite amenable for version control: if one wants to version control the notebook and the outputs then this works quite well. The annoyance comes when one wants only to version control the input, excluding the cell outputs (aka. "build products") which can be large binary blobs, especially for movies and plots.  In particular, I am trying to find a good workflow that:

- allows me to choose between including or excluding output,
- prevents me from accidentally committing output if I do not want it,
- allows me to keep output in my local version,
- allows me to see when I have changes in the inputs using my version control system (i.e. if I only version control the inputs but my local file has outputs, then I would like to be able to see if the inputs have changed (requiring a commit).  Using the version control status command will always register a difference since the local file has outputs.)
- allows me to update my working notebook (which contains the output) from an updated clean notebook. **(update)**

As mentioned, if I chose to include the outputs (which is desirable when using [nbviewer](http://nbviewer.ipython.org) for example), then everything is fine.  The problem is when I *do not* want to version control the output.  There are some tools and scripts for stripping the output of the notebook, but frequently I encounter the following issues:

1. I accidentally commit a version with the the output, thereby polluting my repository.
2. I clear output to use version control, but would really rather keep the output in my local copy (sometimes it takes a while to reproduce for example).
3. Some of the scripts that strip output change the format slightly compared to the `Cell/All Output/Clear` menu option, thereby creating unwanted noise in the diffs. This is resolved by some of the answers.
4. When pulling changes to a clean version of the file, I need to find some way of incorporating those changes in my working notebook without having to rerun everything.
   **(update)**

I have considered several options that I shall discuss below, but have yet to find a good comprehensive solution.  A full solution might require some changes to IPython, or may rely on some simple external scripts.  I currently use [mercurial](https://www.mercurial-scm.org), but would like a solution that also works with [git](https://github.com): an ideal solution would be version-control agnostic.

This issue has been discussed many times, but there is no definitive or clear solution from the user's perspective. The answer to this question should provide the definitive strategy.  It is fine if it requires a recent (even development) version of [IPython](http://ipython.org) or an easily installed extension.

**Update:** I have been playing with [my modified notebook](https://github.com/mforbes/ipython) version which optionally saves a `.clean` version with every save using [Gregory Crosswhite's suggestions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19761645/1115187).  This satisfies most of my constraints but leaves the following unresolved:

1. This is not yet a standard solution (requires a modification of the ipython source.  Is there a way of achieving this behaviour with a simple extension?  Needs some sort of on-save hook.
2. A problem I have with the current workflow is pulling changes.  These will come in to the `.clean` file, and then need to be integrated somehow into my working version.  (Of course, I can always re-execute the notebook, but this can be a pain, especially if some of the results depend on long calculations, parallel computations, etc.)  I do not have a good idea about how to resolve this yet.  Perhaps a workflow involving an extension like [ipycache](https://github.com/rossant/ipycache) might work, but that seems a little too complicated.

## Notes

### Removing (stripping) Output

- When the notebook is running, one can use the `Cell/All Output/Clear` menu option for removing the output.
- There are some scripts for removing output, such as the script [nbstripout.py](https://gist.github.com/minrk/6176788) which remove the output, but does not produce the same output as using the notebook interface.  This was eventually included in the [ipython/nbconvert](https://github.com/ipython/nbconvert) repo, but this has been closed stating that the changes are now included in [ipython/ipython](https://github.com/ipython/ipython),but the corresponding functionality seems not to have been included yet.  **(update)** That being said, [Gregory Crosswhite's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19761645/1115187) shows that this is pretty easy to do, even without invoking [ipython/nbconvert](https://github.com/ipython/nbconvert), so this approach is probably workable if it can be properly hooked in.  (Attaching it to each version control system, however, does not seem like a good idea — this should somehow hook in to the notebook mechanism.)

### Newsgroups

- [Thoughts on the notebook format for version control](http://mail.scipy.org/pipermail/ipython-dev/2011-November/008351.html).

### Issues

- [977: Notebook feature requests (Open)](https://github.com/ipython/ipython/issues/977#issuecomment-5558823).
- [1280: Clear-all on save option (Open)](https://github.com/ipython/ipython/issues/1280). (Follows from [this discussion](https://plus.google.com/103190342755104432973/posts/HsinJRLDj6o).)
- [3295: autoexported notebooks: only export explicitly marked cells (Closed)](https://github.com/ipython/ipython/issues/3295).  Resolved by extension [11 Add writeandexecute magic (Merged)](https://github.com/minrk/ipython_extensions/pull/11).

### Pull Requests

- [1621: clear In[] prompt numbers on "Clear All Output" (Merged)](https://github.com/ipython/ipython/pull/1621). (See also [2519 (Merged)](https://github.com/ipython/ipython/pull/2519).)
- [1563: clear_output improvements (Merged)](https://github.com/ipython/ipython/pull/1563).
- [3065: diff-ability of notebooks (Closed)](https://github.com/ipython/ipython/issues/3065).
- [3291: Add the option to skip output cells when saving. (Closed)](https://github.com/ipython/ipython/pull/3291).  This seems extremely relevant, however was closed with the suggestion to use a "clean/smudge" filter.  A relevant question [what can you use if you want to strip off output before running git diff?](https://github.com/ipython/ipython/pull/3291#issuecomment-17712281) seems not to have been answered.
- [3312: WIP: Notebook save hooks (Closed)](https://github.com/ipython/ipython/pull/3312).
- [3747: ipynb -> ipynb transformer (Closed)](https://github.com/ipython/ipython/pull/3747). This is rebased in [4175](https://github.com/ipython/ipython/pull/4175).
- [4175: nbconvert: Jinjaless exporter base (Merged)](https://github.com/ipython/ipython/pull/4175).
- [142: Use STDIN in nbstripout if no input is given (Open)](https://github.com/ipython/nbconvert/pull/142).

Comment: Sounds like a great thing to add as an issue on http://github.com/ipython/ipython or submit a pull request that helps you further this goal.

Comment: @Kyle As you can see, there is already of plethora of PR's and issues relating to this goal.  Once these are resolved (namely [PR 4175](https://github.com/ipython/ipython/pull/4175)), then a definitive answer should be available but will likely involve some additional scripting outside of IPython (git or hg hooks for example).  Thus, I don't think there will be anything gained by adding a new PR or issue.

Comment: Yeah, their development is moving fast and steadily every day. The devs are good folks though (and have probably read this posting). I know I want an easy workflow for working with git.

Comment: @Kyle I did also mention this on the mailing list.  It looks like [PR 4175](https://github.com/ipython/ipython/pull/4175) will be resolved in a matter of hours/days so I expect this to move quickly.

Comment: Once you have a working script for removing the output, you can use a Git "clean" filter to apply it automatically before committing (see clean/smudge filters).

Comment: All answers are contained in the question! @mforbes, it's fine to answer your own question, but better if you can put the answers in an answer.

Comment: @foobarbecue The question contains unsatisfactory workarounds: each one has at least one limitation.  Now that PR 4175 has been merged, a complete solution can probably be formulated, but this still needs to be done.  As soon as I have some time, I will do it (as an answer) if someone else does not provide a satisfactory solution in the meantime.

Comment: Fair enough. Looking forward to the solution, I'll probably use it.

Comment: Another partial solution: a filter for git that displays cleaner diffs, but still commits the actual notebooks whole and unmodified: https://gist.github.com/takluyver/bc8f3275c7d34abb68bf

Comment: Very good question, but I don't see an accepted answer.  Which answers did you try?  Is there a recommended solution?

Comment: @saroele I have not yet found a recommended solution: I was going to go with the ``--script`` option, but that has been removed.  I am waiting until post-save hooks are implemented ([which are planned](https://github.com/ipython/ipython/issues/6628)) at which point I think I will be able to provide an acceptable solution combining several of the techniques.

Comment: It looks like IPython is getting close.  Once [PR 6896](https://github.com/ipython/ipython/pull/6896) is accepted, then we should be able to resolve this question through pre and post save hooks.

Comment: @mforbes Looks like that PR was just merged a few days after your comment. Could you or someone more knowledgeable than me post an answer here that shows how to use the new feature?

Comment: @kobejohn I will eventually, but am a bit swamped right now.  Maybe somebody else will beat me to it!

Comment: @kobejohn: I just added an answer

Comment: Isn't the best solution a PR to github to just change the diff tool to special case notebook diffs and only show the diff of the input cells? Then you still get the output saved and rendered on GitHub, which is a big useful feature of notebooks.

Comment: Related to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28908319.

Comment: You can use our open-source framework - Ploomber (https://github.com/ploomber/ploomber) exactly for this task. It’s making your work with notebooks faster, helps you export it to raw python files and back to notebooks. That way you can develop production ready code. It's open sourced so most of the ideas in it came from the community and people trying to solve similar issues in the MLops domain.

Comment: Do I understand it right that you would wish to have notebooks where **outputs do not necessarily correspond to input code**? That sounds like a nighmare, if not dangerous. Can I ask why would somebody want that?

Answer (score 139):

Here is my solution with git. It allows you to just add and commit (and diff) as usual: those operations will not alter your working tree, and at the same time (re)running a notebook will not alter your git history.

Although this can probably be adapted to other VCSs, I know it doesn't satisfy your requirements (at least the VSC agnosticity). Still, it is perfect for me, and although it's nothing particularly brilliant, and many people probably already use it, I didn't find clear instructions about how to implement it by googling around. So it may be useful to other people.

1. Save a file with [this content](https://github.com/ivanov/nbutils/blob/master/nbstrip.py) somewhere  (for the following, let us assume `~/bin/ipynb_output_filter.py`)
2. Make it executable (`chmod +x ~/bin/ipynb_output_filter.py`)
3. Create the file `~/.gitattributes`, with the following content

   *.ipynb    filter=dropoutput_ipynb
4. Run the following commands:

   git config --global core.attributesfile ~/.gitattributes
   git config --global filter.dropoutput_ipynb.clean ~/bin/ipynb_output_filter.py
   git config --global filter.dropoutput_ipynb.smudge cat

Done!

**Limitations:**

- it works only with git
- in git, if you are in branch `somebranch` and you do `git checkout otherbranch; git checkout somebranch`, you usually expect the working tree to be unchanged. Here instead you will have lost the output and cells numbering of notebooks whose source differs between the two branches.
- more in general, the output is not versioned at all, as with Gregory's solution. In order to not just throw it away every time you do anything involving a checkout, the approach could be changed by storing it in separate files (but notice that at the time the above code is run, the commit id is not known!), and possibly versioning them (but notice this would require something more than a `git commit notebook_file.ipynb`, although it would at least keep `git diff notebook_file.ipynb` free from base64 garbage).
- that said, incidentally if you do pull code (i.e. committed by someone else not using this approach) which contains some output, the output is checked out normally. Only the locally produced output is lost.

My solution reflects the fact that I personally don't like to keep generated stuff versioned - notice that doing merges involving the output is almost guaranteed to invalidate the output *or* your productivity *or* both.

**EDIT:**

- if you do adopt the solution as I suggested it - that is, globally - you will have trouble in case for some git repo you **want** to version output. So if you want to *disable* the output filtering for a specific git repository, simply create inside it a file *.git/info/attributes*, with

  **.ipynb    filter=

as content. Clearly, in the same way it is possible to do the opposite: enable the filtering *only* for a specific repository.

- the code is now maintained in its own [git repo](https://github.com/toobaz/ipynb_output_filter)
- if the instructions above result in ImportErrors, try adding "ipython" before the path of the script:

  ```
    git config --global filter.dropoutput_ipynb.clean ipython ~/bin/ipynb_output_filter.py
  ```

**EDIT**: May 2016 (updated February 2017): there are several alternatives to my script - for completeness, here is a list of those I know: [nbstripout](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/nbstripout) ([other](https://github.com/kynan/nbstripout) [variants](https://github.com/mforbes/nbstripout)), [nbstrip](https://github.com/ivanov/nbutils/blob/master/nbstrip.py), [jq](http://timstaley.co.uk/posts/making-git-and-jupyter-notebooks-play-nice/).

Comment: How do you deal with the issue of incorporating changes that you pull?  Do you just live with having to regenerate all of the output?   (I think this is a manifestation of your second limitation.)

Comment: I hope I clarified that now!

Comment: There is a small new issue with my approach: if you make an edit, save the notebook, revert the edit and save again, the "signature" may have changed. But it is pointless to show it in the diffs. This, as well as the "output is lost" issue, can be solved by having hidden temporary files. It is a more complex approach, but I plan to implement it sooner or later.

Comment: This solution works really well for my case. I just added `if 'signature' in json_in.metadata: json_in.metadata['signature'] = ""` to this script to strip the signature.

Comment: @DaveP yep, that's the right thing to do. Keeping the signature doesn't make sense, since it also validates the output. I'm editing my answer accordingly, thanks.

Comment: @PietroBattiston: Is it possible that in newer versions of IPython `prompt_number` was replaced with `execution_count`?

Comment: @Dror : absolutely! Edited, thanks. By the way, IPython.nbformat.current was also obsoleted and prints a warning, I will replace that too when I find out how.

Comment: @PietroBattiston Check this out: https://gist.github.com/drorata/f3beb1ae736890b049f6 Feel free to comment there and discuss the matter.

Comment: I'm gettting a `UserWarning: IPython.nbformat.current is deprecated` since upgrading to Jupyter (ipython notebook 3.1.0).  Is there an update for this?

Comment: @zhermes: this extended version should be OK

Comment: @DaveP: (this was the same problem you also highlighted... my version is slightly more backward and forward compatible than yours)

Comment: @zhermes: yes, I should have created a git since long. Done, finally. I don't have time now but next week will debug your error.

Comment: Is there a way to use this git filters method with an external diff tool? The filter is applied if I use the normal command line tool but not if I'm using meld as a diff tool.
http://stackoverflow.com/q/30329615/578770

Comment: @revers No idea unfortunately... a workaround is to make a temporary commit (and compare HEAD rather than just the working dir) which you can then discard/amend.

Comment: To avoid getting `ImportError` I had alter to the above to run using ipython: `git config --global filter.dropoutput_ipynb.clean ipython ~/bin/ipynb_output_filter.py`

Comment: @chris838: thanks. I'm honestly a bit confused by the recent changes in IPython, so I'm currently just reporting your suggestion at the end of the post, then when the migration Jupyter will be settled I will investigate a bit.

Comment: Awsome solution Pietro, thanks :) 

I changed 2 things when using your script in my case:

1) I preferred declaring the filter in .gitattributes in the root of the repo as opposed to `~/.gitattributes`, s.t. other people have the same filters as I do

2) I defined the regexp as `workdir/**/*.ipynb filter=dropoutput_ipynb`, and I put most my notebooks in workdir/ => if I still want to push a notebook with the output and enjoy the bookmarkable rendering in github, I just put it outside that folder.

Comment: this solution is great, thanks :) is it possible to apply this filter backwards across the whole git history? and if so, how can I do that?

Comment: Aha, good question. I guess something like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11397575/2858145) should work, replacing the ``rm...`` command with ``ipynb_output_filter.py`` (or better: a scripts which modifiles the notebooks in place)... but I have no idea of how well it plays with multiple branches

Answer (score 66):

We have a collaborative project where the product is Jupyter Notebooks, and we've use an approach for the last six months that is working great:  we activate saving the `.py` files automatically and track both `.ipynb` files and the `.py` files.

That way if someone wants to view/download the latest notebook they can do that via github or nbviewer, and if someone wants to see how the the notebook code has changed, they can just look at the changes to the `.py` files.

**For `Jupyter` notebook servers**, this can be accomplished by adding the lines

```py
import os
from subprocess import check_call

def post_save(model, os_path, contents_manager):
    """post-save hook for converting notebooks to .py scripts"""
    if model['type'] != 'notebook':
        return # only do this for notebooks
    d, fname = os.path.split(os_path)
    check_call(['jupyter', 'nbconvert', '--to', 'script', fname], cwd=d)

c.FileContentsManager.post_save_hook = post_save
```

to the `jupyter_notebook_config.py` file and restarting the notebook server.

If you aren't sure in which directory to find your `jupyter_notebook_config.py` file, you can type `jupyter --config-dir`, and if you don't find the file there, you can create it by typing `jupyter notebook --generate-config`.

**For `Ipython 3` notebook servers**, this can be accomplished by adding the lines

```py
import os
from subprocess import check_call

def post_save(model, os_path, contents_manager):
    """post-save hook for converting notebooks to .py scripts"""
    if model['type'] != 'notebook':
        return # only do this for notebooks
    d, fname = os.path.split(os_path)
    check_call(['ipython', 'nbconvert', '--to', 'script', fname], cwd=d)

c.FileContentsManager.post_save_hook = post_save
```

to the `ipython_notebook_config.py` file and restarting the notebook server.  These lines are from a github issues answer [@minrk provided](https://github.com/ipython/ipython/issues/8009) and @dror includes them in his SO answer as well.

**For `Ipython 2` notebook servers**, this can be accomplished by starting the server using:

```
ipython notebook --script
```

or by adding the line

```
c.FileNotebookManager.save_script = True
```

to the `ipython_notebook_config.py` file and restarting the notebook server.

If you aren't sure in which directory to find your `ipython_notebook_config.py` file, you can type `ipython locate profile default`, and if you don't find the file there, you can create it by typing `ipython profile create`.

Here's [our project on github that is using this approach](https://github.com/ioos/secoora):  and here's a [github example of exploring recent changes to a notebook](https://github.com/ioos/secoora/commit/470cda0e620b6259bfdcfd96e323e5a9e6459fb5).

We've been very happy with this.

Comment: Thanks for the added evidence that using ``--script`` has worked in practice.  The problem with this is that the actual notebooks might be huge if images are kept.  An ideal solution along this way might use something like [git-annex](https://git-annex.branchable.com) to keep track of only the latest full notebook.

Comment: In Ipython 3.x the `--script` is deprecated. http://ipython.org/ipython-doc/3/whatsnew/version3.html

Comment: Thanks @dror, I've updated my answer to provide minrk's ipython 3.x solution as you also provided here.

Comment: just in case anyone wondered, the '--to script' argument *appears* to be identical to the '--to python' argument that shows up in the link @Dror sent. i diff'd some output on the two conversions of a somewhat complex notebook and saw no differences

Comment: Here are full instructions for a post-save hook to save both `.py` and `.html` from IPython notebooks: http://protips.maxmasnick.com/ipython-notebooks-automatically-export-py-and-html

Comment: **Update:** This solution is broken in iPython version 4, because of "The Big Split" of Jupyter from iPython. To adjust this solution to version 4, use the command `jupyter notebook --generate-config` to create a config file. The command `jupyter --config-dir` finds out which directory contains the config files. And the code snippet given by @Rich should be added to the file named `jupyter_notebook_config.py`. The rest works as before.

Comment: But I don't see in this answer what is done to the notebook files? Same as in favorite answer?

Comment: Would be great to have a separate menu item for Jupyter menu item: Save & commit. So it saves without output content and calls a script for (git) commit. Created https://github.com/jupyter/notebook/issues/1410

Comment: In addition to the point by @mobiusdumpling, replace the `check_call(['ipython'` with `check_call(['jupyter'`, otherwise you will get a warning that `ipython nbconvert` is deprecated and you should use `jupyter nbconvert` instead. (Jupyter v4.1.0, iPython v4.1.2)

Comment: If you want to save `.py` files to a different directory other than the current one, add `'--output-dir', 'your_dir'` to `check_call`. e.g., `check_call(['jupyter', 'nbconvert', '--to', 'script', fname, '--output-dir', './src'], cwd=d)`

Comment: This also works for Jupyter Lab, you just need to edit `jupyter_lab_config.py` instead of `jupyter_notebook_config.py`

Answer (score 41):

I have created [`nbstripout`](https://github.com/kynan/nbstripout), based on [MinRKs gist](https://gist.github.com/minrk/6176788), which supports both Git and Mercurial (thanks to mforbes). It is intended to be used either standalone on the command line or as a filter, which is easily (un)installed in the current repository via `nbstripout install` / `nbstripout uninstall`.

Get it from [PyPI](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/nbstripout) or simply

```
pip install nbstripout
```

Comment: I am considering a workflow where I keep both .ipynb and corresponding .py automatically created using post-save hooks described above. I would like to use .py for diffs - would nbstripout be able to clear .py file from the cell execution counters (# In[1] changed to In[*]), so that they don't clutter the diffs or should I create a simple script for doing that?

Comment: @KrzysztofSłowiński No, `nbstripout` doesn't support this use case easily since it relies on the JSON format of the Notebook. You're likely better off writing a script specialized to your use case.

Comment: Does `nbstripout` have an option to work recursively on a given folder (I'm talking about the executable itself)?

Comment: Not directly, and it doesn't need to. You can simply use `find` or some other standard way of recursively finding files you want to operate on.

Answer (score 30):

Since there exist so many strategies and tools to handle version control for notebooks, I tried to create a flow diagram to pick a suitable strategy (created April 2019)

[image: Decision flow to pick version control strategy]

Comment: As of March 2023, nbdime is probably the first option you want to check if you are using Github, not ReviewNB. See the GitHub blog post, ["Feature Preview: Rich Jupyter Notebook Diffs"](https://github.blog/changelog/2023-03-01-feature-preview-rich-jupyter-notebook-diffs/).

Answer (score 23):

The very popular 2016 answers above are inconsistent hacks compared with the better way to do this in 2019.

Several options exist, the best that answers the question is Jupytext.

[Jupytext](https://github.com/mwouts/jupytext)

Catch the [Towards Data Science article on Jupytext](https://towardsdatascience.com/introducing-jupytext-9234fdff6c57)

The way it works with version control is you put both the .py and .ipynb files in version control. Look at the .py if you want the input diff, look at the .ipynb if you want the latest rendered output.

Notable mentions: VS studio, nbconvert, nbdime, hydrogen

I think with a little more work, VS studio and/or hydrogen (or similar) will become the dominant players in the solution to this workflow.

Comment: This should be the top answer, jupytext is the way to go.

Answer (score 22):

After a few years of removing outputs in notebooks, I have tried to come up with a better solution. I now use [Jupytext](https://github.com/mwouts/jupytext), an extension for both Jupyter Notebook and Jupyter Lab that I have designed.

Jupytext can convert Jupyter notebooks to various text formats (Scripts, Markdown and R Markdown). And conversely. It also offers the option to **pair** a notebook to one of these formats, and to automatically synchronize the two representations of the notebook (an `.ipynb` and a `.md/.py/.R` file).

Let me explain how Jupytext answers the above questions:

> allows me to choose between including or excluding output,

The `.md/.py/.R` file only contains the input cells. You should always track this file. Version the `.ipynb` file only if you want to track the outputs.

> prevents me from accidentally committing output if I do not want it,

Add `*.ipynb` to `.gitignore`

> allows me to keep output in my local version,

Outputs are preserved in the (local) `.ipynb` file

> allows me to see when I have changes in the inputs using my version control system (i.e. if I only version control the inputs but my local file has outputs, then I would like to be able to see if the inputs have changed (requiring a commit). Using the version control status command will always register a difference since the local file has outputs.)

The diff on the `.py/.R` or `.md` file is what you are looking for

> allows me to update my working notebook (which contains the output) from an updated clean notebook. (update)

Pull the latest revision of the `.py/.R` or `.md` file and refresh your notebook in Jupyter (Ctrl+R). You will get the latest input cells from the text file, with matching outputs from the `.ipynb` file. The kernel is not affected, which means that your local variables are preserved - you can continue you work where you left it.

What I love with Jupytext is that the notebook (under the form of a  `.py/.R` or `.md` file) can be edited in your favorite IDE. With this approach, refactoring a notebook becomes easy. Once you're done you just need to refresh the notebook in Jupyter.

If you want to give it a try: install Jupytext with `pip install jupytext` and restart your Jupyter Notebook or Lab editor. Open the notebook that you want to version control, and *pair it* to a Markdown file (or a Script) using the [Jupytext Menu](https://github.com/mwouts/jupytext#jupytext-menu-in-jupyter-notebook) in Jupyter notebook (or the [Jupytext commands](https://github.com/mwouts/jupytext#jupytext-commands-in-jupyterlab) in Jupyter Lab). Save your notebook, and you'll get the two files: the original `.ipynb`, plus the promised text representation of the notebook, that is a perfect fit for version control!

For those who may be interested: Jupytext is also available on the [command line](https://jupytext.readthedocs.io/en/latest/using-cli.html).

Answer (score 18):

> **Update**: Now you can [edit Jupyter Notebook](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/jupyter-support)
>   files directly in Visual Studio Code. You can choose to edit the
>   notebook or the converted python file.

**I finally found a productive and simple way to make Jupyter and Git play nicely together.** I'm still in the first steps, but I already think it is a lot better than all other convoluted solutions.

[Visual Studio Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/) is a cool and open source code editor from Microsoft. It has an excellent Python extension that now allows you to [import a Jupyter Notebook](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/editing#_jupyter-code-cells) as python code. Now you also can directly [edit Jupyter Notebooks](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/jupyter-support).

After you import your notebook to a python file, all the  code and markdown will be together in a ordinary python file, with special markers in comments. You can see in the image below:

[image: VSCode editor with a notebook converted to python]

Your python file just has the contents of the notebook input cells. The output will be generated in a split window. You have pure code in the notebook, it doesn't change while you just execute it. No mingled output with your code. No strange JSON incomprehensible format to analyze your diffs.

Just pure python code where you can easily identify every single diff.

I don't even need to version my `.ipynb` files anymore. I can put a `*.ipynb` line in `.gitignore`.

Need to generate a notebook to publish or share with someone? No problem, just [click the export button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53376454/vscode-how-to-export-a-python-file-that-was-imported-from-a-jupyter-notebook-ba) in the interactive python window

[image: Exporting a python file to Notebook format]

If you are editing the notebook directly, there's now a icon `Convert and save to a python script`.
[image: Jupyter icons in Visual Studio Code]

Here a screenshot of a notebook inside Visual Studio Code:

[image: Editing Notebook inside VSCode]

I've been using it just for a day, but finally I can happily use Jupyter with Git.

P.S.: VSCode code completion is a lot better than Jupyter.

Comment: Do you know how this is exporting to pdf, the actual command it is using? 

When using vscode I can convert to a pdf and retain matplotlib plots. However, when using jupyterlab the resulting pdf doesn't keep any of the output. Ideally I'd like to use jupytext to produce pdfs with no code but with output

Comment: @bryce, I don't know. But take a look of pure Jupyter instead of JupyterLab. I think its export function works better.

Answer (score 14):

(2017-02)

**strategies**

- on_commit():

  - strip the output > name.ipynb (`nbstripout`, )
  - strip the output > name.clean.ipynb (`nbstripout`,)
  - always `nbconvert` to python: name.ipynb.py (`nbconvert`)
  - always convert to markdown: name.ipynb.md (`nbconvert`, `ipymd`)
- vcs.configure():

  - git difftool, mergetool: nbdiff and nbmerge from nbdime

**tools**

- `nbstripout`: strip the outputs from a notebook

  - src: https://gist.github.com/minrk/6176788
  - src: https://github.com/kynan/nbstripout

    - `pip install nbstripout; nbstripout install`
- `ipynb_output_filter`: strip the outputs from a notebook

  - src: https://github.com/toobaz/ipynb_output_filter/blob/master/ipynb_output_filter.py
- `ipymd`: convert between {Jupyter, Markdown, O'Reilly Atlas Markdown, OpenDocument, .py}

  - src: https://github.com/rossant/ipymd
- **`nbdime`**: "Tools for diffing and merging of Jupyter notebooks." (2015)

  - src: https://github.com/jupyter/nbdime
  - docs: http://nbdime.readthedocs.io/

    - `nbdiff`: compare notebooks in a terminal-friendly way

      - **nbdime nbdiff works as a git diff tool**: https://nbdime.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#git-integration-quickstart
    - `nbmerge`: three-way merge of notebooks with automatic conflict resolution

      - **nbdime nbmerge works as a git merge tool**
    - `nbdiff-web`: shows you a rich rendered diff of notebooks
    - `nbmerge-web`: gives you a web-based three-way merge tool for notebooks
    - `nbshow`: present a single notebook in a terminal-friendly way

Answer (score 13):

Here is a new solution from Cyrille Rossant for IPython 3.0, which persists to markdown files rather than json-based ipymd files:

https://github.com/rossant/ipymd

Comment: Not supporting Jupyter yet, it seems.

Comment: I'm using ipymd successfully with the latest Jupyter -- do you get any specific problem or error message?

Answer (score 9):

Just come across "jupytext" which looks like a perfect solution. It generates a .py file from the notebook and then keeps both in sync. You can version control, diff and merge inputs via the .py file without losing the outputs. When you open the notebook it uses the .py for input cells and the .ipynb for output. And if you want to include the output in git then you can just add the ipynb.

https://github.com/mwouts/jupytext

Answer (score 8):

As pointed out by, the `--script` is deprecated in `3.x`. This approach can be used by applying a post-save-hook. In particular, add the following to `ipython_notebook_config.py`:

```py
import os
from subprocess import check_call

def post_save(model, os_path, contents_manager):
    """post-save hook for converting notebooks to .py scripts"""
    if model['type'] != 'notebook':
        return # only do this for notebooks
    d, fname = os.path.split(os_path)
    check_call(['ipython', 'nbconvert', '--to', 'script', fname], cwd=d)

c.FileContentsManager.post_save_hook = post_save
```

The code is taken from [#8009](https://github.com/ipython/ipython/issues/8009).

Comment: Thanks for demonstrating the use of a post-save hook.  Unfortunately, as mentioned elsewere, getting back from the ``.py`` file to a notebook is problematic, so this is unfortunately not a complete solution.  (I kind of wish it was as it is very nice to diff ``.py`` files instead of notebooks.  Perhaps the new [notebook diff](https://github.com/ipython/ipython/pull/7861#issuecomment-77680169) feature will be useful.

Comment: Thanks! I am now using this trick to reproduce the `--script` behavior, regardless of version control. I had some problems at first, so just in case I can save someone some time: 1) If the `ipython_notebook_config.py` is missing from the profile folder, run `ipython profile create` to generate it. 2) If it seems as though the post-save-hook is ignored, run ipython with `--debug` to diagnose the problem. 3) If the script fails with error `ImportError: No module named mistune` - simple install minstue: `pip install mistune`.

Answer (score 7):

Unfortunately, I do not know much about Mercurial, but I can give you a possible solution that works with Git, in the hopes that you might be able to translate my Git commands into their Mercurial equivalents.

For background, in Git the `add` command stores the changes that have been made to a file into a staging area.  Once you have done this, any subsequent changes to the file are ignored by Git unless you tell it to stage them as well.  Hence, the following script, which, for each of the given files, strips out all of the `outputs` and `prompt_number sections`, stages the stripped file, and then restores the original:

**NOTE:** If running this gets you an error message like `ImportError: No module named IPython.nbformat`, then use `ipython` to run the script instead of `python`.

```py
from IPython.nbformat import current
import io
from os import remove, rename
from shutil import copyfile
from subprocess import Popen
from sys import argv

for filename in argv[1:]:
    # Backup the current file
    backup_filename = filename + ".backup"
    copyfile(filename,backup_filename)

    try:
        # Read in the notebook
        with io.open(filename,'r',encoding='utf-8') as f:
            notebook = current.reads(f.read(),format="ipynb")

        # Strip out all of the output and prompt_number sections
        for worksheet in notebook["worksheets"]:
            for cell in worksheet["cells"]:
               cell.outputs = []
               if "prompt_number" in cell:
                    del cell["prompt_number"]

        # Write the stripped file
        with io.open(filename, 'w', encoding='utf-8') as f:
            current.write(notebook,f,format='ipynb')

        # Run git add to stage the non-output changes
        print("git add",filename)
        Popen(["git","add",filename]).wait()

    finally:
        # Restore the original file;  remove is needed in case
        # we are running in windows.
        remove(filename)
        rename(backup_filename,filename)
```

Once the script has been run on the files whose changes you wanted to commit, just run `git commit`.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  Mercurial does not really have a staging area like git (though one could use [mercurial queues](http://stevelosh.com/blog/2010/08/a-git-users-guide-to-mercurial-queues/) for this purpose).  In the meantime, I tried adding this code to a save hook that saves a clean version with a ``.clean`` extension.  Unfortunately, I could not see how to do this without [directly modifying IPython](https://github.com/mforbes/ipython/commit/f70e4046) (although this change was quite trivial).  I will play with this for a while and see if it suits all of my needs.

Answer (score 7):

I use a very pragmatic approach; which work well for several notebooks, at several sides. And it even enables me to 'transfer' notebooks around. It works both for Windows as Unix/MacOS.
Al thought it is simple, is solve the problems above...

## Concept

Basically, do **not** track the `.ipnyb`-files, only the corresponding `.py`-files.
By starting the *notebook-server* with the `--script` option, that file is automatically created/saved when the notebook is saved.

Those `.py`-files do contain all input; non-code is saved into comments, as are the cell-borders. Those file can be read/imported ( and dragged) into the notebook-server to (re)create a notebook. Only the output is gone; until it is re-run.

Personally I use *mercurial* to version-track the `.py` files; and use the normal (command-line) commands to add, check-in (ect) for that. Most other (D)VCS will allow this to.

Its simple to track the history now; the `.py` are small, textual and simple to diff. Once and a while, we need a clone (just branch; start a 2nd notebook-sever there), or a older version (check-it out and import into a notebook-server), etc.

## Tips & tricks

- Add **.ipynb* to '**.hgignore**', so Mercurial knows it can ignore those files
- Create a (bash) script to start the server (with the `--script` option) and do version-track it
- Saving a notebook does save the `.py`-file, but does *not* check it in.

  - This is a **drawback**: One can forget that
  - It's a **feature** also: It possible to save a notebook (and continue later) without clustering the repository-history.

## Wishes

- It would be nice to have a buttons for check-in/add/etc in the notebook Dashboard
- A checkout to (by example) `file@date+rev.py`) should be helpful
  It would be to much work to add that; and maybe I will do so once. Until now, I just do that by hand.

Comment: How do you go from the ``.py`` file back to a notebook?  I like this approach, but because ``.ipynb`` -> ``.py`` -> ``.ipynb`` is potentially lossy, I did not consider this seriously.

Comment: That is easy: load it, by example by dropping it on de Notebook-dashboard. Except of "output data" nothing is lost

Comment: If that is true, then I think this would be close to idea, but I seem to recall that IPython made no commitment to completely preserving data in the transition from ``.py`` to ``.ipynb`` formats. There is an [issue about this](https://github.com/ipython/ipython/issues/1823) – so perhaps this will form the basis for a complete solution.

Comment: I am having some difficult converting from ``.py`` files to ``.ipynb`` files.  ``nbconvert`` does not yet seem to support this, and I do not have a notebook dashboard since I run ``ipython notebook`` manually.  Do you have any general suggestions about how to implement this backwards conversion?

Comment: Surely the `.py`-to-notebook transformation is not intended to round-trip. So this can't really be a general solution though it's nice it works for you.

Comment: This method now fails as ``--script`` was removed as an option.  It should be reinstated when IPython 3.0 is released though.  Still can't figure out a good way of getting the ``.py`` files into a notebook without writing a custom converter.

Comment: I roundtrip `.ipynb` through Markdown (of all things!) for version control using [Notedown](http://github.com/aaren/notedown). This gives me the option of stripping output before commits, but more importantly for my current use case (an online course), Markdown is much easier to refactor.

Normally it's very hard to do reorganisation in a set of Notebooks: Moving multi-cell chunks around within a Notebook or between Notebooks, reordering, promoting or demoting sections, splitting or merging Notebooks, etc. All this is easy in Markdown (given a good text editor).

Comment: @mforbes you can use my fancy script: https://github.com/petered/plato/blob/3f28dd763ce3fdee5d52d52bdef76a57cc6cf450/notebooks/py_file_to_notebooks.py, though yes, of course there are some things in the ipynb format that won't be conserved in the ipynb to py to ipynb journey

Answer (score 5):

I will also add to others suguested https://nbdev.fast.ai/ which is a state of the art "literate programming environment, as envisioned by Donald Knuth back in 1983!".

It also has some git hooks that help a little https://nbdev.fast.ai/#Avoiding-and-handling-git-conflicts and the other commands like:

- nbdev_read_nbs
- nbdev_clean_nbs
- nbdev_diff_nbs
- nbdev_test_nbs

So you can also create your documentation on the go as while writing a library for example some of them:

- https://dev.fast.ai/
- https://ohmeow.github.io/blurr/
- https://rbracco.github.io/fastai2_audio/

You can see a video here [nbdev tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Hrs7iEYmRmg) apart from the first link.

Comment: I have not had a chance to look deeply, but this does not seem to support what Knuth calls "tangling", which is one of the major points of literate programming.  This allows you to write the code in the order that makes sense for explanation, while retaining the appropriate order needed on disk.  For example [14_callback.schedule.ipynb](https://github.com/fastai/fastai2/blob/master/nbs/14_callback.schedule.ipynb) seems to start with the import statements - the least important part of the code.  Tangling allows you to defer this until after the main concepts have been described.

Comment: Well, not so sure if it does indeed handle `tangling` or not, but the "real" python file generated from that file is [fastai2/callback/schedule.py](https://github.com/fastai/fastai2/blob/master/fastai2/callback/schedule.py), I added a youtube video I havent watched.

Comment: As of October 2022, nbdev2 has improved the workflow using git with notebooks, it basically solves problems with git conflicts: https://nbdev.fast.ai/tutorials/git_friendly_jupyter.html

Comment: Here is a nice explanation: https://www.fast.ai/posts/2022-08-25-jupyter-git.html

Answer (score 4):

I've built python package that solves this problem

https://github.com/brookisme/gitnb

It provides a CLI with a git-inspired syntax to track/update/diff notebooks inside your git repo.

Heres' an example

```
# add a notebook to be tracked
gitnb add SomeNotebook.ipynb

# check the changes before commiting
gitnb diff SomeNotebook.ipynb

# commit your changes (to your git repo)
gitnb commit -am "I fixed a bug"
```

Note that last step, where I'm using "gitnb commit" is committing to your git repo.  Its essentially a wrapper for

```
# get the latest changes from your python notebooks
gitnb update

# commit your changes ** this time with the native git commit **
git commit -am "I fixed a bug"
```

There are several more methods, and can be configured so that it requires more or less user input at each stage, but thats the general idea.

Answer (score 4):

This is April-2020 and there are lots of strategies and tools for Jupyter notebook version control. Here's a quick overview of all the tools you can use,

- [nbdime](https://github.com/jupyter/nbdime) - Nice for local diff'ing and merging of notebooks
- [nbstripout](https://github.com/kynan/nbstripout) - A git filter to automatically remove notebook outputs before each commit
- [jupytext](https://github.com/mwouts/jupytext) - Keeps a .py companion file sync'ed to each notebook. You only commit .py files
- [nbconvert](https://github.com/jupyter/nbconvert) - Convert notebooks to a python script or HTML (or both) and commit these alternate file types
- [ReviewNB](https://www.reviewnb.com/) - Shows notebook diff (along with output) for any commit or pull request on GitHub. One can also write comments on notebook cells to discuss changes (screenshot below).

[image]

Disclaimer: I built ReviewNB.

Comment: With jupytext you can also use a system committing both notebook and .py code right?

Answer (score 3):

To follow up on the excellent script by Pietro Battiston, if you get a Unicode parsing error like this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/kwisatz/bin/ipynb_output_filter.py", line 33, in <module>
write(json_in, sys.stdout, NO_CONVERT)
  File "/Users/kwisatz/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/IPython/nbformat/__init__.py", line 161, in write
fp.write(s)
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\u2014' in position 11549: ordinal not in range(128)
```

You can add at the beginning of the script:

```
reload(sys)
sys.setdefaultencoding('utf8')
```

Answer (score 3):

After digging around, I finally found [this relatively simple pre-save hook on the Jupyter docs](http://jupyter-notebook.readthedocs.io/en/latest/extending/savehooks.html#examples). It strips the cell output data. You have to paste it into the `jupyter_notebook_config.py` file (see below for instructions).

```
def scrub_output_pre_save(model, **kwargs):
    """scrub output before saving notebooks"""
    # only run on notebooks
    if model['type'] != 'notebook':
        return
    # only run on nbformat v4
    if model['content']['nbformat'] != 4:
        return

    for cell in model['content']['cells']:
        if cell['cell_type'] != 'code':
            continue
        cell['outputs'] = []
        cell['execution_count'] = None
        # Added by binaryfunt:
        if 'collapsed' in cell['metadata']:
            cell['metadata'].pop('collapsed', 0)

c.FileContentsManager.pre_save_hook = scrub_output_pre_save
```

From [Rich Signell's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25765194/3217306):

> If you aren't sure in which directory to find your `jupyter_notebook_config.py` file, you can type `jupyter --config-dir` [into command prompt/terminal], and if you don't find the file there, you can create it by typing `jupyter notebook --generate-config`.

Comment: I would note that this solution would never save _any_ outputs to disk, and is somewhat independent of the version control issue.

Answer (score 1):

I did what Albert & Rich did - Don't version .ipynb files (as these can contain images, which gets messy).  Instead, either always run `ipython notebook --script` or put `c.FileNotebookManager.save_script = True` in your config file, so that a (versionable) `.py` file is always created when you save your notebook.

To regenerate notebooks (after checking out a repo or switching a branch) I put the script [py_file_to_notebooks.py](https://github.com/petered/plato/blob/3f28dd763ce3fdee5d52d52bdef76a57cc6cf450/notebooks/py_file_to_notebooks.py) in the directory where I store my notebooks.

Now, after checking out a repo, just run `python py_file_to_notebooks.py` to generate the ipynb files.  After switching branch, you may have to run `python py_file_to_notebooks.py -ov` to overwrite the existing ipynb files.

Just to be on the safe side, it's good to also add
`*.ipynb` to your `.gitignore` file.

Edit: I no longer do this because (A) you have to regenerate your notebooks from py files every time you checkout a branch and (B) there's other stuff like markdown in notebooks that you lose.  I instead strip output from notebooks using a git filter.  Discussion on how to do this is [here](https://gist.github.com/minrk/6176788).

Comment: I liked this idea, but after testing, found that the conversion from ``.py`` files back to ``.ipynb`` is problematic, especially with version 4 notebooks for which there is not yet a converter.  One would currently need to use the v3 importer then convert to v4 and I am a bit concerned about this complicated trip.  Also, a ``.py`` file is not a very good choice if the notebook is primarily Julia code!  Finally, ``--script`` is deprecated so I think hooks are the way to go.

Comment: The git filter solution in your link is good, you should copy your answer from there here :-)

Answer (score 1):

Ok, so it looks like the current best solution, as per a discussion [here](https://gist.github.com/minrk/6176788), is to make a git filter to automatically strip output from ipynb files on commit.

Here's what I did to get it working (copied from that discussion):

I modified cfriedline's nbstripout file slightly to give an informative error when you can't import the latest IPython:
https://github.com/petered/plato/blob/fb2f4e252f50c79768920d0e47b870a8d799e92b/notebooks/config/strip_notebook_output
And added it to my repo, lets say in `./relative/path/to/strip_notebook_output`

Also added the file .gitattributes file to the root of the repo, containing:

```
*.ipynb filter=stripoutput
```

And created a `setup_git_filters.sh` containing

```
git config filter.stripoutput.clean "$(git rev-parse --show-toplevel)/relative/path/to/strip_notebook_output" 
git config filter.stripoutput.smudge cat
git config filter.stripoutput.required true
```

And ran `source setup_git_filters.sh`.  The fancy $(git rev-parse...) thing is to find the local path of your repo on any (Unix) machine.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this jupyter extension. It will enable you to directly upload your ipython notebooks to github.

https://github.com/sat28/githubcommit

I have also created a video demonstrating the steps -
[youtube link](https://youtu.be/vKx_4zFvOi8)

Comment: can you explain what this does? The doumentation is not especially clear.

Comment: @AlexMonras This will directly add a button in jupyter notebook from where you can push notebooks to your GitHub repo with a commit message

Answer (score 0):

How about the idea discussed in the post below, where the output of the notebook should be kept, with the argument that it might take a long time to generate it, and it is handy since GitHub can now render notebooks. There are auto-save hooks added for exporting .py file, used for diffs and .html for sharing with team members who do not use notebooks or git.

https://towardsdatascience.com/version-control-for-jupyter-notebook-3e6cef13392d

Answer (score 0):

Here's my solution: https://github.com/frankharkins/squeaky

It's a script that removes noise from the notebooks, and can be used as a pre-save hook, so that you never save the noise to disk. Also published to PyPI so everyone on your team (plus CI) can install it easily.

You can extend the instructions in the README to add a short function that strips outputs too, or I can add that as a feature if anyone requests it.