# Does Mercurial have something like git's "filter" feature?

Tags: mercurial

Git has a "filter" feature, which makes it possible to check in a processed version of files. E.g., [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20844506/699305) shows how IPython notebook files can be filtered so that embedded output data is excluded from commits. Basically:

1. Create a filter script, e.g., `dropoutput`, and put it in your path.
2. Create the file `~/.gitattributes`, with the following content

   ```
   *.ipynb    filter=ipynb_filter
   ```
3. Run some more configuration commands to put it all together ("ipynb_filter" is just a symbolic name, so it needs to be pointed to the filter script.)

The effect is that when you try to check in a `.ipynb` file, you actually check in the filtered version. The file in the working directory is not altered (but presumably has status "clean" since it has just been committed).

So: Is there a way to get the same functionality in mercurial? I googled and dug around the help a little but nothing came up.

Comment: Thanks, indeed that question comes pretty close. The `[encode]`/`[decode]` device is tagged as an "unloved" feature (aka "we'd deprecate it if we could"), but that doesn't disqualify it as an answer I guess...

Comment: Just marked my own question as duplicate. I really like this new(?) feature! :-) (The action shows as [Community](http://stackoverflow.com/users/-1/community) for some reason).