# Can I configure Jupyter Notebook to split source files and generated files?

Tags: jupyter, jupyter-notebook

I really like [Jupyter Notebooks](http://jupyter.org/).
However, working with them is cumbersome in conjunction with a source control system like `git`, because an `ipynb`-File contains the source code (what you actually write in the notebook) and the generated output text / HTML / images / metadata / ...

For example, merge conflicts are difficult to resolve now, because everything is stored in one huge file with lots of generated data.

I wonder if I can configure Jupyter to store notebooks as

- **A source file**: For example, I imagine this to be a Markdown file where everything surrounded by three backticks (```) is interpreted as a code cell. Diffs of that file would be meaningful and merge conflicts would be simple to resolve manually.
- **A generated file**: This contains everything else. If there is a merge conflict within this file, it can be resolved by regenerating it.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

For reference: There is [a slightly more general version of this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18734739/using-ipython-notebooks-under-version-control/20844506) which lists various efforts at adapting IPython and Jupyter to this effect, and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18734739/using-ipython-notebooks-under-version-control/20844506#20844506) proposes to solve the problem via Git. There is [a Github project](https://gist.github.com/pbugnion/ea2797393033b54674af) with a Git filter based on that answer, and (in its edit at the end) the answer links a few similar tools like [nbstripout](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/nbstripout/0.2.0).