# Search Jupyter notebook markdown cells from command line

Tags: grep, jupyter-notebook, markdown, ack, ag

I use [`ag`](https://github.com/ggreer/the_silver_searcher) to search through my notes. My notes are written down in Markdown files and Markdown cells contained within Jupyter notebooks.

I can search the Markdown files conveniently with `ag --markdown ...`. It would be very handy if something similar could be done with the Jupyter notebook files. But this would require that `ag` understands the format of these notebooks.

My question: is there a way to search **only** the Markdown cells for a given string in a Jupyter notebook file? Any pattern matcher used in the solution is acceptable for me (`ag`, `grep`, `ack`, ...).

**p.s.** The notebooks are composed in JSON. Here's a sample:

```
$ head notebook.ipynb
{
 "cells": [
  {
   "cell_type": "markdown",
   "metadata": {},
   "source": [
    "THIS IS A MARKDOWN STRING"
   ]
  },
  {
```

Comment: Can you expand on your question. From the sounds of it, your just asking how to provide a path to the directory you which to search, which is the standard approach to using ag.

Comment: Thanks for your interest. Hopefully I've clarified my question -- see the edit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd look to use `jq` to filter out all markdown cells of a python notebook. For instance, if you just wanted to spit out all the markdown source, you could use the following:

```
$< notebook.ipynb | jq '.cells[]|select(.cell_type == "markdown")|.source[]'
```

jq is fast, and used for far more elaborate solutions when saving ipython notebooks to git, for example: [Using IPython notebooks under version control](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18734739/using-ipython-notebooks-under-version-control)

Comment: This is indeed an order of magnitude faster than @gboffi's answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if `ag` can be interfaced with a filter, but to
get the Markdown out of a notebook file the following Python code will suffice

```
import nbformat
from sys import argv
nb = nbformat.read(argv[1], nbformat.NO_CONVERT)
for cell in nb.cells:
    if cell.cell_type == 'markdown' : print(cell.source)
```