# How to use nbconvert as git textconv driver to enable effective version control of Jupyter Notebooks

Tags: python, git, jupyter-notebook, diff

#### What I'm trying to do and how it differs from similar problems

I would like to version control Jupyter Notebooks using Git. Unfortunately, by default, Git and Jupyter Notebooks do not play nicely. An `.ipynb` file is a `.json` file containing not only the Python code itself but also plenty of metadata (e.g., cell execution counts) and cell output.

Most existing solutions (e.g., [Using IPython notebooks under version control](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18734739/using-ipython-notebooks-under-version-control)) rely on removing output and metadata from the notebook. This (i) still maintains the `.json` file structure when diffing, which is a pain to read, and (ii) means that features such as output display on Github cannot be used, because the output gets removed before committing.

My idea is the following: Whenever I run `git diff`, Git automatically uses `jupyter nbconvert --to python filename.ipynb` to convert from my `*.ipynb` source files to `*.py` plain python files. It should then only detect changes that affect the code itself (not execution counts and output, as those are removed by `nbconvert`) without actually removing them and it should make my diffs much more readable than they are for unconverted `.ipynb` files. I do not want the `.py` version of the file to be stored permanently; it should only be used for `git diff`. My understanding is that this should be possible by simply specifying `nbconvert` as the `[diff] textconv` driver, but I have not been able to get it to work.

### Steps I have performed so far

I have created a file named `ipynb2py` in `/usr/local/bin` containing

```
#!/bin/bash
jupyter nbconvert --to python $1
```

I have added the following to my `.gitconfig` file

```
[diff "ipynb"]
    textconv = ipynb2py
```

and the following to my `.gitattributes` file

```
*.ipynb diff=ipynb
```

to assign the `ipynb` textconv driver to all files of the `.ipynb` format.

Now, I would expect `git diff` to automatically perform a conversion (I know this will slow down substantially but it's worth having a viable option for VCing notebooks) every time I run it and then show a nice readable diff, based only on the difference between notebook states *after conversion*.

When I do a `git diff`, it first says `[NbConvertApp] Converting notebook`, which tells me that Git is triggering the conversion as expected. However, the conversion fails after a long Python traceback ending in `fatal: unable to read files to diff`.

Immediately before the `fatal` error message, I receive the following

```
nbformat.reader.NotJSONError: Notebook does not appear to be JSON: '\n# coding: utf-8\n\n# In[ ]:\n\nimport...
```

Of course, I suspected that there was a problem with the way in which my `ipynb2py` script was invoking `nbconvert`, but running `ipynb2py notebook.ipynb` in my repo works perfectly well, so that cannot be the reason.

What could be causing this error? What are the requirements for a valid `textconv` driver other than returning a text file?

#### Complete traceback

```
git diff
[NbConvertApp] Converting notebook /var/folders/9t/p55_4b9971j4wwp14_45wy900000gn/T//lR5q08_notebook.ipynb to python
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/Users/user/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/nbformat/reader.py", line 14, in parse_json
nb_dict = json.loads(s, **kwargs)
File "/Users/user/anaconda/lib/python3.6/json/__init__.py", line 354, in loads
return _default_decoder.decode(s)
File "/Users/user/anaconda/lib/python3.6/json/decoder.py", line 339, in decode
obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
File "/Users/user/anaconda/lib/python3.6/json/decoder.py", line 357, in raw_decode
raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 2 column 1 (char 1)

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/Users/user/anaconda/bin/jupyter-nbconvert", line 11, in <module>
load_entry_point('nbconvert==5.1.1', 'console_scripts', 'jupyter-nbconvert')()
File "/Users/user/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/jupyter_core/application.py", line 266, in launch_instance
return super(JupyterApp, cls).launch_instance(argv=argv, **kwargs)
File "/Users/user/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/traitlets/config/application.py", line 658, in launch_instance
app.start()
File "/Users/user/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/nbconvert/nbconvertapp.py", line 305, in start
self.convert_notebooks()
File "/Users/user/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/nbconvert/nbconvertapp.py", line 473, in convert_notebooks
self.convert_single_notebook(notebook_filename)
File "/Users/user/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/nbconvert/nbconvertapp.py", line 444, in convert_single_notebook
output, resources = self.export_single_notebook(notebook_filename, resources, input_buffer=input_buffer)
File "/Users/user/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/nbconvert/nbconvertapp.py", line 373, in export_single_notebook
output, resources = self.exporter.from_filename(notebook_filename, resources=resources)
File "/Users/user/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/nbconvert/exporters/exporter.py", line 171, in from_filename
return self.from_file(f, resources=resources, **kw)
File "/Users/user/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/nbconvert/exporters/exporter.py", line 189, in from_file
return self.from_notebook_node(nbformat.read(file_stream, as_version=4), resources=resources, **kw)
File "/Users/user/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/nbformat/__init__.py", line 141, in read
return reads(fp.read(), as_version, **kwargs)
File "/Users/user/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/nbformat/__init__.py", line 74, in reads
nb = reader.reads(s, **kwargs)
File "/Users/user/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/nbformat/reader.py", line 58, in reads
nb_dict = parse_json(s, **kwargs)
File "/Users/user/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/nbformat/reader.py", line 17, in parse_json
raise NotJSONError(("Notebook does not appear to be JSON: %r" % s)[:77] + "...")
nbformat.reader.NotJSONError: Notebook does not appear to be JSON: '\n# coding: utf-8\n\n# In[ ]:\n\nimport...
fatal: unable to read files to diff
```

Answer (score 2):

If you carefully read the [documentation of `gitattributes`](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitattributes#_generating_diff_text) (where the `textconv` config option is described) you will notice that the converter program must send the output to standard output:

> ...
>
> #### Performing text diffs of binary files
>
> Sometimes it is desirable to see the diff of a text-converted version
>   of some binary files. For example, a word processor document can be
>   converted to an ASCII text representation, and the diff of the text
>   shown. Even though this conversion loses some information, the
>   resulting diff is useful for human viewing (but cannot be applied
>   directly).
>
> The `textconv` config option is used to define a program for
>   performing such a conversion. The program should take a single
>   argument, the name of a file to convert, and ***produce the resulting
>   text on stdout.***
>
> ...

Therefore you must add the `--stdout` option to your conversion command:

**ipynb2py**

```
#!/bin/bash
jupyter nbconvert --to python --stdout "$1"
```

Answer (score 0):

have you tried just straight up committing the notebooks. I saw similar posts to you when looking on version controlling jupyter notebooks, but when i just tried it it seemed to work fine.

example notebook on github

https://github.com/loegare/Test-Post-Please-Ignore/blob/master/Untitled%20Folder/Data%20Due%20Dilligence.ipynb

Comment: They're rendered very nicely on Github, but that was never the problem. As nice as they look on Github, `git diff` still sees a changed execution count as a change made to the file and chart output as huge blocks of binary. This becomes a real pain when you're trying to use Jupyter notebooks in a Git workflow with multiple collaborators.

Comment: i suppose thats fair. I guess im not really in that environment. thanks for clarifying for me