# Using git version control with jupyter notebooks

Tags: python, git, version-control, jupyter-notebook

Is there a recommended way of managing changes and merges between branches working with the same notebook? It looks like there are always too many conflicts even if the output is cleaned before pushing.

Comment: This seems to be a dupe of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51340802/how-to-use-nbconvert-as-git-textconv-driver-to-enable-effective-version-control and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18734739/using-ipython-notebooks-under-version-control. Do you have a situation not covered by these questions?